# dynamic textview attributes

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to dynamically create a textview and set attributes.

```
LinearLayout timeBar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_cells);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
timeBar.addView(tv);
```

I need to be able to set the height to match parent, the width to zero, the weight will be some % of 100 and I also need to set the background colour. Is this even possible?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes it is. Check the TextView and LayoutParams classes.

Comment: yes it is very much possible. Any attribute you give in xml. Can be gave through code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just make an instance of [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html). It has a constructor for width, height, and weight.  Then, call `tv.setLayoutParams()`.

In this case, you use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` because your `TextView` is going inside a `LinearLayout`.  Here's a more formal example:

```
LinearLayout timeBar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_cells);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
float weight = 0.5f; //your value goes here.
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, weight));
timeBar.addView(tv);
```